# What CMS will run with Amazons SimpleDB?

Tags: .net, content-management-system, amazon-simpledb

We are committed to SimpleDB. Most of our clients interaction will be through a desktop application. But we still need a web presence where they can create accounts and where we can add new content.

Ideally this would be a .NET CMS, but I think that's asking too much. Failing a .NET-CMS-AWS solution, is a CMS out there that can be modified to work with SimpleDB? Well, as long as the modifications would take less time than rolling our own!